# SonarQube Duplicate Keys not allowed

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

We've recently migrated and upgraded our sonarqube environment. We have a jenkins server separate from our sonar server.

Our sonar builds produce the following error, and I've been searching everywhere for a solution and cannot find one. I don't know a huge amount about sonarqube configuration or jenkins configuration, which may be why I'm unable to solve the problem.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-
plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) on project project-name: Unable to register 
extension org.sonar.api.config.PropertyDefinition: Duplicate Keys not 
allowed. Duplicate for 'org.sonar.api.config.PropertyDefinition-
sonar.dbcleaner.cleanDirectory' -> [Help 1]
```

We have the following plugins installed on sonar:

```
Checkstyle [checkstyle] 2.2 Analyze Java code with Checkstyle.
Cobertura [cobertura] 1.6.3 Get code coverage with Cobertura.
Database Cleaner [dbcleaner] 4.5.4 Optimizes database performances by removing old and useless data.
Design [design] 4.5.4 Analyze Java bytecode to compute O.O. metrics and extract dependencies between resources.
Findbugs [findbugs] 3.2 Analyze Java code with Findbugs 3.0.1.
Java [java] 3.0 SonarQube rule engine.
JavaScript [javascript] 2.3 Enables analysis of JavaScript projects.
Motion Chart [motionchart]  1.7 Display how a set of metrics evolves over time (requires an internet access).
PDF Report [pdfreport]  1.4 SonarQube plugin for PDF reporting
PMD [pmd]   2.3 Analyze Java code with PMD.
Surefire [surefire] 3.3.2   Get results of unit tests with Surefire.
Useless Code Tracker [uselesscodetracker]   1.0 Reports on source code that can be reduced.
Web [web]   2.3 Analyze HTML (also within PHP/Ruby/etc. templates) and JSP/JSF code.
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The Database Cleaner plugin seemed to be causing the issue. The version may have been incompatible with SonarQube5.0.1. Issue resolved.